# How to use for loop under the for loop

Tags: shell-script

In this script it gets the server list from file *vmr.txt* and after it tried to find out log files which is more than 500M and move.

I stuck here with the find redirect, I do pass the multiple output of finds to next command in side the for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

$tdate=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`

for vm in `(cat /nodes/vmr.txt | awk '{print$2}'|| sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')`
do

ssh pbc01@$vm `find /var/log/vmr/ -type f -size +500M |grep -v ".gz"`

ssh pbc01@$vm gzip -c $file > "$file"."$tdate".gz && cp -v /dev/null "$file"
ssh pbc01@$vm  mv /var/log/vmr/*.gz /vmr/oldlog/
  done
```

Comment: Could you possibly clean up the code a bit and format it properly with a 4 space indent?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid processing the output of `ls` or, equivalently here, `find`.  Everything you're doing could be a single find command though:

```
ssh pbc01@"$vm" find /var/log/vmr -type f -size +500M -not -name '*gz' -exec sh -c 'gzip -c "$1" > "$1.$tdate.gz"' "" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

you could even have the `gzip` write directly to `/vmr/oldlog` instead of moving it after by just putting that path as part of the target of gzip